# is refactoring available in Adobe brackets

Tags: javascript, eclipse, dreamweaver, adobe-brackets

It is so great that code completion is already there but two things are also important to have
1- refactoring ( renaming all the incidents of same variable/ function )
2- when you select a variable it  to highlight all the occurrences of that variable

I wonder if the 1,2 are available yet as I need a JavaScript IDE to have both plus code-completion. I badly searched for all three Eclipse too. but then Eclipse doesn't have code-completion

Answer (score 2):

1) Check out the ["Rename JavaScript Identifier" extension](https://github.com/asgerf/bracket-rename). (The Replace All command built into Brackets is more powerful than what most text editors give you, but it's not a true 'rename refactoring' -- it's not type-aware and currently only replaces within a single file).

2) Check out the ["Quick Search" extension](https://github.com/enturn/brackets-quick-search).

Answer (score 1):

I use [Ternific](https://github.com/MiguelCastillo/Brackets-Ternific) ("*JavaScript hinting and refactoring powered by Tern*") which can do more than the above mentioned extension. Still renames on Ctrl+R.